# grep for a variable content with a dot

Tags: bash, grep

i found  many similar questions about my issue but i still don't find the correct one for me.
I need to grep for the content of a variable plus a dot but it doesn't run escaping the dot after the variable. For example:
The file content is

```
item.
newitem.
```

My variable content is `item.` and i want to grep for the exact word, therefore I must use `-w` and not `-F` but with the command I can't obtain the correct output:

`cat file | grep -w "$variable\."`

Do you have suggestions please?

Hi, I have to rectify my scenario. My file contains some FQDN and for some reasons I have to look for `hostname.` with the dot.
Unfortunatelly the grep -wF doesn't run:
My file is

```
hostname1.domain.com
hostname2.domain.com
```

and the command

```
cat file | grep -wF hostname1.
```

doesn't show any output. I have to find another solution and I'm not sure that `grep` could help.

Comment: From your original input, it seemed to be desired to only match words. That's why choroba's correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298549/6176817) uses the `-w` option. Just drop it and it will work for your updated input: `grep -F hostname1. file`.

Comment: Glad it works for you :) Please, consider accepting [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298549/6176817).

Comment: You are right. I'm sorry for confusion. Both `-w` and `-F` don't run and I don't understand very well the why but I resolved using `grep "^$hostname\."`.

Comment: Are you sure [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298549/6176817) doesn't work? It should work without the `-w` option :)

Answer (score 8):

If $variable contains `item.`, you're searching for `item.\.` which is not what you want. In fact, you want `-F` which interprets the pattern literally, not as a regular expression.

```
var=item.
echo $'item.\nnewitem.' | grep -F "$var"
```

Comment: thanks but I need to rectify my scenario: the content file has some rows with some fqdn so I need to grep using "hostname." but grep -wF doesn't run

Comment: @intore it is not clear what is not working.. but you can change your sample input and exact grep command you are using to show the failing case...

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing variable and append `\.` to it, which results in calling

`cat file | grep -w "item.\."`.

Since `grep` accepts files as parameter, calling `grep "item\." file` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep "\b$word\."
```

---

1. `\b`: word boundary
2. `\.`: the dot itself is a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` solution may help you in same.

```
awk -v var="item." '$0==var'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

from man grep

> ```
> -w, --word-regexp
>           Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
>           character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
> ```

and

> ```
> The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
>    The  symbols  \<  and  \>  respectively  match  the  empty string at the beginning and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string
>    provided it's not at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a synonym for [[:alnum:]] and \W is a synonym for [^[:alnum:]].
> ```

as the last character is a `.` it must be followed by a non word `[A-Za-z0-9_]` however the next character is `d`

```
grep '\<hostname1\.'
```

should work as `\<` ensures previous chracter is not a word constituent.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically construct the search pattern and then call grep

```
rexp='^hostname1\.'

grep "$rexp" file.txt
```

The single quotes tell bash not to interpret special characters in the variable. Double quotes tell bash to allow replacing $rexp with its value. The caret ( ^ ) in the expression tells grep to look for lines starting with 'hostname1.'